# In Electron version 1.X, how can I emit an event from one BrowserWindow and consume it in another BrowserWindow?

Tags: javascript, chromium, electron

In Electron version 1.X, how can I emit an event from one BrowserWindow and consume it in another BrowserWindow?

I am using Electron version 1.2.1.

Comment: You could send to main using the `ipcRenderer` and the reply can go to the other window instance reference that you should have in the main process. Consult https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-renderer.md

Comment: @OwenAyres You should convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: Thanks @VadimMacagon - forgot about this, was short on time yesterday! Added some code that should cover this solution

Comment: @OwenAyres thanks, in the end I used 'ipcRenderer.send()' from to emit an event from the render process and 'ipcMain.on()' to listen to the event in the main process.

Comment: @Kosmo good, glad you got something working, that's what I was thinking at the time of my comment and is basically what the posted answer covers now incase anybody else is hunting for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is using the `ipcRenderer` to communicate between `BrowserWindow` instances and the `main` process. For example, in the main process you could have something like the following: -

```
const electron          = require('electron');
const app               = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow     = electron.BrowserWindow;
let mainWindow, subWindow;

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    fullscreen: true
});

mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/../index.html');

subWindow = new BrowserWindow(); // etc

electron.ipcMain
    .on('myMainMessage', function (event, data) {
        // data can be passed from browser window
        subWindow.webContents.send('myPassedMessage', data);
    });
```

Then, inside the first `mainWindow` instance you could throw together a message using the `ipcRenderer` like so: -

```
var electron = require('electron');
var ipc = electron.ipcRenderer;

ipc.send('myMainMessage', {
    property: 'someValue'
});
```

And inside your other window instance you'd have some JavaScript to listen to the other trigger. Something like this: -

```
var electron = require('electron');
var ipc = electron.ipcRenderer;

ipc.on('myPassedMessage', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data); // will be from the mainWindow instance
});
```

Consult [the docs on the ipcRenderer section](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-renderer.md) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Communication example from a child_window to its parent_window using [webContents](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md):

- Inside parent_window:

  ```
  const BrowserWindow = require('electron').remote.BrowserWindow;

  var child_window = new BrowserWindow({ ... });

  child_window.webContents.on("event", function(arg1, arg2){
      console.log(arg1, arg2); // this will print inside parent_window devtools console
  });
  ```
- Inside child_window:

  ```
  require('electron').remote.getCurrentWebContents().emit("event", "hello", "world");
  ```

The main advantage using this solution instead of the [IPC](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md) one is that those routines are linked to the local context of child_window's [webContents](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md). So those routines are deleted if the child_window is closed and its [BrowserWindow](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md) object is deleted.

You can also use the same system to communicate from parent_window to child_window.